# How to get the value after read specific word from Microsoft Word?

Tags: vb.net

I want to get the particular value from Microsoft Word after read the specific word

For example if a word document which has text as follows:

Customer Details

Date: 23/6/2013

Name: Jason

Cust ID: A2441

So i want the program read if have word "Date" then it will get the value 23/6/2013 and place into textbox.

Then it will continue read word "Name" then will get Jason into textbox2.

How to get the value of date after i read date?

```
    Dim fd As OpenFileDialog = New OpenFileDialog()

    fd.Title = "Open"
    fd.InitialDirectory = "C:\Documents"
    fd.Filter = "Word 97-2003 Documents (*.doc)|*.doc|Word Documents(*.docx)|*.docx"
    fd.RestoreDirectory = True
    If fd.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
        txtQuotaFileName.Text = fd.FileName
    End If

    Dim sReader As New StreamReader(fd.FileName)
    Dim text As String = sReader.ReadToEnd()
    sReader.Close()
    If text.Contains("Date") Then
        'Get the value after Date :
    End If
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using the following line:

`Split(stringval,"Date:")(1)`